# Python: how to parse the output of a linux command using compile and split

Tags: python

I need to write a script using re.compile and split to take in the cmd and print out the ip address(last col) and the date and time and convert it to epoch time.
I was using just re.compile but was mentioned to me to use the split command to make it easier.. just looking for some guidance?
this is what the output looks like

```
host:~ # last -a -F | egrep -v "boot|wtmp|tty"
root     pts/2        Fri Jun 19 10:32:13 2015   still logged in                       xx.x.xx.xx
root     pts/0        Fri Jun 19 08:22:29 2015   still logged in                       xx.xx.xx.xx
root     pts/5        Thu Jun 18 10:09:30 2015 - Thu Jun 18 17:20:52 2015  (07:11)     xx.xx.xx.xx
root     pts/4        Thu Jun 18 09:53:33 2015 - Thu Jun 18 17:04:53 2015  (07:11)     xx.xx.xx.xx
    last_re = re.compile(r'(?P<user>\S+)\s+(?P<pts>\/.+)\s(?P<day>\S+)\s+(?P<month>)\s+(?P<date>\d+)\s+(?P<stime>(\d\:\d)\s+(?P<hyphen>(\s|-)\s+(?P<endtime>(\d\:\d)\s+(?P<user>)\s+(?P<duration>(\(\d\:\d\))\s+(?P<ipaddress>(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$)')
    cmd = 'last -a -F | egrep -v "boot|wtmp|tty"'

    try:
            status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
            print last_re;
            if not status:
                    output_lines = output.split('\n')
                    m = last_re.search(output_lines[1])
                    if m:
                            print "<day='%s' month='%s' time='%s' external_ip='%s'/>" % (m.group('day'), m.group('month'), m.group('stime'), m.group('ipaddress'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. No need of python.

```
last -a -F | egrep -v "boot|wtmp|tty" | awk '/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/{print $0}'
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I need to create it in python as this script will get called by another python script. It is for running health checks on the system.

Comment: In general, piping a grep to awk is not a good idea: you can probably do the same with awk alone.

Comment: Also, `awk '/pattern/ {print $0}'` can be simplified to just `awk '/pattern/'` because `print $0` is the default behaviour when a condition evaluates to True.

Answer (score 0):

`split()` might be a bit difficult with the spacing, so here's an example with regex. It looks behind for a '-' followed by whitespace, captures everything non-greedy after that up to and including four digits (year), skips everything up to a ')' and then more whitespace until it hits what is the first two octets of an IP separated by a '.', which is captured along with the rest of the IP before the end of line.

```
import re
import time

str = "root     pts/4        Thu Jun 18 09:53:33 2015 - Thu Jun 18 17:04:53 2015  (07:11)     192.168.0.10"

rx = re.compile(r'(?<=-)\s+(.*?\d{4}).*?(?<=\))\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.*)$')

date, ip = rx.search(str).group(1,2)
epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date.strip(), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")))

print(ip, epoch)
```

Output:

```
192.168.0.10 1434668693
```

Comment: great thank you stevieb.. this has worked for me.. thanks for the feedback